# Need to get the command line of all the daemons that are running

Tags: shell-script, command-line, filenames, ps, daemon

I used the below command to list down all the daemons that are in a machine

```
/sbin/initctl list | awk '{ if ($1 == "tty") print $1" "$2; else print $1; }'
```

Now my next requirement is to get the daemons running path i.e command line.

For instance `vmsd  /usr/sbin/vmsd`

So gave couple of tries using the `ps aux` command followed by the `grep` command but I am not getting the results as expected.

Can some one help me out with this?

Comment: If you can find the PID, use `cat /proc/$pid/cmdline` perhaps.

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DopeGhoti [answered in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340569/need-to-get-the-command-line-of-all-the-daemons-that-are-running#comment602075_340569):

> If you can find the PID, use cat /proc/$pid/cmdline